# How do you manage your server infos(IP/Name)

Tags: linux, networking, hostname

In my company, on one know the exact server infos. An excel file is used to maintain all server lists(hostname/ip), but does not update on time.

Someone may create several servers but forgot to add it to excel file and sometimes later he quit the company. So no one know how many servers we have.

How do you manage server info? I hope there is a Web UI, so we can manage it.

Comment: Seems to be a human problem, not a technical one. Excel sheet, webapp, etc...there is always opportunity for someone to get lazy and not document things.

Comment: Agreed with EEAA - no matter how flashy the interface, if humans are a required step, it will fall out of sync and fail.

Comment: I know its human problem. But also I want to upgrade the way to maintain server list. Some Web UI.

Answer (score 1):

The best method would be to use a configuration management solution like Chef, and require all machines to be Cheffed (via image or other solution). That way you can not only get a list of machines, but get a vast amount of attributes like exact software installed, CPU core count, memory, OS/kernel version etc. Makes handling security issues like POODLE/OpenSSL much easier.

If you don't want to go to that effort, and you have a specific network subnet, I'd recommend doing some clever work with nmap. You could setup a cronjob with something along the lines of:

`nmap -sP <network range> > $DATETIME.txt` and have `logrotate` rotate it daily.

It's kludgy, but it's a 30s solution that might be somewhat better than excel sheets.